# PHP Reflection - Static Parent Method from Child

Tags: php

Is it possible to have a static method in an abstract class, populate a child class?

I am trying to understand reflection in PHP (coming from C# world) and I have an abstract class which I extend in another class.

I want to populate the properties of my child class with a static method from my parents class.

Possible?

I have the latest PHP5 and 7 available to me.

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Can you show us a little piece of code illustrating your question?!

Comment: Yes. The data provider class can be viewed here: https://github.com/DeltaWolf7/Arc/blob/master/app/classes/DataProvider.class.php and a class extending it here: https://github.com/DeltaWolf7/Arc/blob/master/app/classes/User.class.php I want to make the getByID method in the data provider static and use it to populate the calling child. Am I right in thinking I need to be looking at get_class?

Comment: In best case you enrich your question with corresponding code snippets. Its easy to point out the problem you have.

Comment: Btw. if you make `getId()` static, you cannot use `$this` in it. As you works with objects from `User` it makes no sense to make getId() static. Its smells like a little bit of failure by design.